# Print all powersets of an array giving wrong answer

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an integer array nums of unique elements, return all possible subsets (the power set).
The belwo code is returning wrong answer for input [1,2].How to fix it?

Expected   Output is

> [[],[1],[2],[1,2]]

I am getting the below output

> [[],[2],[2,1],[2,1,2]]

I have written the below code

```
class Solution {
    
    private List<List<Integer>> ans= new ArrayList<>();
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        
        
        
        solve(nums,0,new ArrayList<>()) ;
        
        return ans;
        
    }
    
    
    public void solve(int[] nums,int i,List<Integer> output)
    {
        if(i==nums.length )
        {
            
            ans.add(new ArrayList(output));
            return;
            
        }
        
        
       // exclude the element
        solve(nums,i+1,output);
        
        
        //include the element
        output.add(nums[i]);
        solve(nums,i+1,output);
        
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure your approach is right. you add element to your running list `output` but then you don't remove it which is what an usual backtracking does. You add to the running list, recurse and then remove the last element chosen. The correct `solve` looks like:

```
    public static void solve(int[] nums,int i,List<Integer> output)
    {
        ans.add(new ArrayList<>(output));
        while (i < nums.length) {
            output.add(nums[i]);
            solve(nums, i+1, output);
            output.remove(output.size()-1);
            i++;
        }
        
    }
```

You can see that I added nums[i] to the output , recurse on the remaining list and then removed the last element added.

Output for example input [1,2] with this method is:

```
[[], [1], [1, 2], [2]]
```

Comment: i want to understand why we do this?`output.remove(output.size()-1);`

Comment: This is the same thing as include an element solve and exclude element as you wrote in the comments in your code.

Comment: my code works fine if i include remove()

Comment: But that will invoke your solve so many times. You don't need to call it twice.

Comment: My code runs fine in leetcode.I am not sure how we can optimise
`https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/733573318/`